# jQuery .animate

Tags: jquery

I have the following issue: a list item that once clicked, a div slides up and changes opacity to 1. My goal is that on second click, the same div will get opacity 0.

I tried removing the original class and adding a new one, "selected" and then apply a click event on that. For some reason, the second part is not working. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li.slide1').click(function () {
        $("div#slidebox1").animate({
            opacity: .8,
            top: -200,

        }, 300);

        $("li.slide1").removeClass("slide1").addClass("selected");

    });

    $("li.selected").click(function () {

        $("div#slidebox1").animate({
            opacity: 0,

        }, 300);

    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. Please read the [faq]. It would be good if you'd invest more time into [tidying up your question](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to be readable if you want people to assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use .on() for jQuery 1.7+ or .live() jQuery 1.3+ because you add "selected" class when user click on li.slide1 and it does't exist before.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li.slide1').live('click',function () {
        $("div#slidebox1").animate({ opacity: .8, top: -200 }, 300);
        $(this).removeClass("slide1").addClass("selected");
    });

    $("li.selected").live('click', function () {
        $("div#slidebox1").animate({ opacity: 0 }, 300);
    });
});
```

Comment: Short of using a very old version of jQuery, you shouldn't ever be using `.live()`. If you need to delegate events (that's what this process is called) then you should use the `.delegate()` function if you're prior to jQuery 1.7 and don't have access to `.on()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul").on("click", "li.selected", function () {
   $("div#slidebox1").animate({ opacity:0},300);
});
```

Use `on()` to delegate your handling of the second click.

Your current code is setting up two `click` handlers on `document.ready()` - but since the `li`'s don't have the class `selected` yet they don't have handlers applied to them. Using `on()` sets the handler to the `ul`, which catches the bubbling click event, and checks to see if it's target is `li.selected` and invokes your function.

Also, as gdoron is suggesting below, you could include binding a handler in the `callback` to your first function.

```
$('li.slide1').click(function () {
    $("div#slidebox1").animate({
        opacity: .8,
        top: -200
    }, 300, function(){
         $(this).one("click", function(){
            $("div#slidebox1").animate({opacity:0}, 300);
         });
    });

    $("li.slide1").removeClass("slide1").addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: Why? people here think `on` is the answer for every question, well it's not.

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work in this case. If you've got a better answer @gdoron, please, share it. Otherwise, is it so hard to make your comments constructive?

Comment: P.s. The answer should be `callback` to the animate function. Edit: just did.

Comment: This is great, but it seems to 'take over' my first click event.so, when I click the item the first time, it slides up and then fades out.

Comment: add `return false;` to your first click handler (at the end). This will stop the event from bubbling up to the `ul`.

Comment: this seems to eliminate the rest of the code. the 'on' doesn't work.

Comment: @gdoron - apparently `live()` is better.